# Aesthetics of buttons and menu elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my problem:

- If you resize the following page (by making it smaller), the Home and Dropdown buttons are of different sizes.
- Also, the 'burger menu' that appears on your right, when clicked becomes a different size.
- The search bar does not fill 100% of the width.

How do I fix these problems?

This part of a tab menu that I will reuse for my site.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function mySecondFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


/* The search field */

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}


/* The search field when it gets focus/clicked on */

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}


/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}


/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="mySecondFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#base">Base</a>
      <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
      <a href="#support">Support</a>
      <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few small issues with your code.

- First the difference in the size of the buttons is because you have not specified the line height of your elements. Once you define the line-height as 1 then all the size issues get resolved.

  `.topnav a,
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    line-height: 1;
  }`
- For the width of search, you just need to give width:100%; to your search box.

  `#myInput {
    width: 100%;
  }`

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function mySecondFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {

  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


/* The search field */

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}


/* The search field when it gets focus/clicked on */

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}


/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}


/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}


/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  #myInput {
    width: 100%;
    }
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="mySecondFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#base">Base</a>
      <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
      <a href="#support">Support</a>
      <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and awesome response, it solved my issue!

Comment: Please click on the check box on left of the answer to close the question.

Comment: Sorry, one last minor question before I close the topic - how do I put a little 'down' arrow beside the Dropdown button to indicate to users that it is a drop-down menu?

Comment: you can use Font Awesome.